# How to fix the error "unsupported format string passed to tuple.__format__" in Python

Tags: python, printing, formatting, numbers

I am trying to print the Pearson correlation in Python using the formatting. I am using Python 3.7, after following the syntax. I got this error, please what could possibly be the issue?

```
mpg1 = mtcars['mpg']
hp = mtcars['hp']
qsec = mtcars['qsec']
wt = mtcars['wt']

pearsonr_coefficient = pearsonr(mpg1,hp)
print('The personR correlation is {0:.3f}'.format(pearsonr_coefficient))

Exception has occurred: TypeError
unsupported format string passed to tuple.__format__
```

Comment: what is the object type and value of `pearsonr_coefficient`?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that this `personr` function is returning you a tuple instead of a number. You should subset that tuple to get a number and it will work